# show all data from a table

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

Currently after doing a query to mysql all data is shown in a HTML table ex:

membership-number | name | surname | address | age | nationality | id | card | profession..

Problem is that all content is squeezed up and not showing nice in the HTML table.

I would like to have maybe just the membership-number, name and surname showing and once you click on the membership-number all the data is then shown neatly.

Not sure what I need to use if it is JavaScript or not but would apprciate if you can at least give me a clue on how to be able to show all the data in a neat way.

Thanks

Comment: you need to (1) tell us the expected output (2) the actual output and (c) what is the code you are using

Comment: this is the html and php: echo "<th>" . "Client No"  . "</th><th>" . "Name" . "</th><th>" . "Surname"  . "</th><th>" . "Town"  . "</th><th>" . "Telephone"  . "</th><th>" . "Mobile"  . "</th><th>" . "ID Card"  . "</th><th>" . "Username"  . "</th><th>" . "Password";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['surname'] . "</td><td>" . $row['town'] . "</td><td>" . $row['telephone'] . "</td><td>" . $row['mobile'] . "</td><td>" . $row['idcard'] . "</td><td>" . $row['username'] . "</td><td>" . $row['password'];
echo "</tr>";

Comment: (1) expected output is to show each result after being clicked in a new box  (2)actual output is that all results are shown in an html table but there is too much information. (c) Using html and php

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want an HTML table that displays the membership-number, name and surname of each member. When you click on the membership-number, you want it to display the rest of the detail. I think Surreal Dreams is right about using Javascript to do that part.

It could look something like this (please excuse pseudocode - can't remember foreach syntax):

```
echo "<table id='data'>";
foreach ($row in $sqltable)
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><a onclick='displaymoreinfo'>".$row['id']."</a></td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['surname']."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";    
} 
echo "</table>";
```

Then, you'd need a javascript method at the top of the file that did something like what this person has here: 
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/03/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript.html

-Laura

Comment: exactly you understood my requirement correctly, doing so the html table would not be cluttered and all the information would be shown nicely on a new window (being javascript or whatever)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use jQuery and [datatables](http://datables.net/).

Used together with your normal HTML, your tables are instantly transformed into sortable, paginated, styled etc. tables. You can of course choose the settings you want to apply.

You can also write your own PHP table class or script which together with CSS renders the data depending on your inputs. You can then specify these parameters using PHP arrays, something like this maybe:

PHP:

Let's say your SQL query script eventually returns the table data as something like this:

```
$tbl_data = array(
   0 => array("nr" => "10", "name" => "John", "surname" => "Smith", "address" => " Plaza Hotel Room 12", "age" => "44", "nat" => "Syldavian", "id" => "12345", "card" => "MasterCard", "prof" => "Pet Washer"),
   1 => array("nr" => "11", "name" => "Captain", "surname" => "Haddock", "address" => "Marlinspike Hall", "age" => "55", "nat" => "British", "id" => "133455", "card" => "Discovery", "prof" => "Captain")
```

);

Then you can maybe specify your input parameters like this:

```
$arr_cols = array("nr" => "Membership Number", "name" => "Name", "surname" => "Surname", "address" => "Address", "age" => "Age", "nat" => "Nationality", "id" => "ID", "card" => "Card", "prof" => "Profession");

$arr_align = array("nr" => "center", "name" => "left", "surname" => "left", "address" => "left", "age" => "center", "nat" => "center", "id" => "center", "card" => "left", "prof" => "left");

$lst_show = array("nr", "name", "surname");
```

This table view method can then always be used, independent of your specific inputs:

```
$html = "<table class='grid'>\n";
// headings
foreach ($arr_cols as $key => $title) {
    if (in_array($key, $lst_show))
        $html .= "<tr><th>$title</th></tr>\n";
} 
//rows
foreach ($tbl_data as $arr_row) {
   foreach ($arr_row as $key => $data) {
     if (in_array($key, $lst_show)) {
        $align = !empty($arr_align[$key]) ? " align='" . $arr_align[$key] . "'" : '';
        $html .= "<tr><td$align>$data</td></tr>\n";
    }
  }
}
$html .= "</table>\n";

echo $html;
```

CSS:

```
table.grid {border:1px solid blue; etc.}
table.grid th {etc.}
table.grid td {etc.}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of definition lists for such a task, but you could combine that with a table for the same effect. Here's a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/rZfKg/

Comment: More info is not clickable (PHP): echo  '<dl>';
echo    "<dt>" . $row['id'] . "</dt>";
echo     '<dd>';
echo      '<dl>';
echo            '<dt id="more_info_header">More Info</dt>';
echo                '<dd id="more_info">';
echo                   '<dl>';
echo                        '<dt>Device</dt>';
echo                        "<dd>" . $row['device'] . "</dd>";
echo                       '<dt>Brand</dt>';
echo                        "<dd>" . $row['brand'] . "</dd>";
echo                    '</dl>';
echo                '</dd>';
echo            '</dl>';
echo        '</dd>';
echo    '</dl>';

Comment: $ is not defined in firefox web console

Comment: $("#more_info_header").on is not a function

Comment: @user1347219 This fiddle works ok in my Firefox. From your errors, it sounds like you are copying this code but haven't loaded jQuery properly in your own page.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that if you want to output your data and then change the displayed info based on user interaction, you will need JavaScript.  Specifically, I suggest jQuery for this kind of thing.  You'll still need to work out a nice neat way to display your data with HTML and CSS, and then have JavaScript/jQuery reveal the nice presentation.

However, presenting "neatly" is pretty subjective - you'll have to decide what you want to display and how to lay it out, and that will be all CSS and HTML.  I will tell you right off the bat, avoid tables - go for good clean semantic HTML.

Comment: actually a pop up window (showing all row data) after clicking on a particular result would be excellent, will take your suggestions and will see